# Clearing the log associated with a tracelistener after each run?

Tags: c#, logging, app-config, trace

I'm using TextWriterTraceListener for logging, which is being configured into the app using app.config as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="100"  >
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
             initializeData="MyLog.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

How do I ensure that the logging starts afresh (clearing the previous contents) after each run, rather than appending to the contents to the existing log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to derive your own Custom TraceListener from the `TextWriterTraceListener` class. [Here's a sample](http://davebost.com/blog/2004/04/30/rolling-over-textwritertracelistner-logs/) that rolls a new log file at every interval. You should be able to modify this implementation.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, the link is broken.